# How Do I Pass an Array of Values via Anchor Tag Helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using `Asp.Net Core 2.1` `Pages`

```
public async Task OnGetAsync([FromQuery(Name = "status")] string[] myValues)
{

}
```

I'm trying to pass in an array of values from an `anchor tag helper`, but all I receive in `myValues` is one item. If I manually type out the query string to mirror `MyRoute?myValues=A&myValues=B`, it works as expected. I've tried the following with no success.

```
<a asp-page="/MyPage" asp-route-status="A" asp-route-status="B">Click</a>

<a asp-page="/MyPage" asp-route-status="new [] { A, B }">Click</a>

<a asp-page="/MyPage" asp-route-status="@(new [] { A, B })">Click</a>

@{  var list = new string[] { "A", "B" };}
<a asp-page="/MyPage" asp-route-status="@list">Click</a>
```

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. You're not passing *anything* because your action is looking for something named `v` but all your sending is `status` (and twice, which makes no sense). What have you tried? What is not working? Be specific.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Typo when pasting the code in there. Fixed it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Beyond the typo, I'm not what further explanation is needed. I want to pass in ```A``` & ```B``` as an array for the status parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to send both `A` and `B` in a single param? As in an array containing `A` and `B`? If so, you should just do `asp-route-status="new[] { A, B }"`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Exactly. I want to send both ```A``` and ```B``` as values for ```status```. Your suggestion doesn't work unfortunately. If I do what you suggested, there will be 1 item in ```myValues``` and the value is literally ```new[] { A, B }```.

Comment: Try prefixing it with an @, `@new[] { ... }`. If that still doesn't work, set a variable with it first and then use that variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177756/discussion-between-james-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible - The value passed in to `asp-route-status` is expected to either be a string or a value that it is then converted to a string anyway. You can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs#L136), where the `RouteValues` property is a dictionary of `<string, string>`.

Let's look at your first example, which looks like this:

```html
<a asp-page="/MyPage" asp-route-status="A" asp-route-status="B">Click</a>
```

I'm using Visual Studio with all its intellisense magic - when I use this code snippet, I am warned via a green squiggly and tooltip that the *"Attribute 'asp-route-status' already exists."*. The end result here is that only the first value specified is actually passed into the query-string.

With either of your valid array approaches, the generated value for `status` is simply a `ToString` of the array - *System.String%5B%5D*.

It appears that in order to achieve what you want, you're going to need to fallback to the traditional `UrlHelper` approach. Here's what that looks like:

```html
<a href="@Url.Page("/MyPage", new { status = new [] { "A", "B" } })">Click</a>
```

I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2119) Github issue where the most recent comment (2017-11-24) asks about how to achieve this with a tag-helper, but the question has not been answered as of today (2018-08-10).