# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages multiselect input and pagination

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm following the official Microsoft tutorial for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and I'm working on adjusting the pagination portion located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to work for my site.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder,
    string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex)
{
    CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    DateSort = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        pageIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    CurrentFilter = searchString;

    IQueryable<Student> studentIQ = from s in _context.Student
                                    select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        studentIQ = studentIQ.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            studentIQ = studentIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
            break;
        case "Date":
            studentIQ = studentIQ.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            studentIQ = studentIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
            break;
        default:
            studentIQ = studentIQ.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 3;
    Student = await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(
        studentIQ.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
}
```

For my site, the equivalent of `SearchString` is a multiselect select box. This gets passed through to the page as a string array. I can't find any documentation on how to format that into the cshtml portion of a link that works for a normal string.

Essentially I need to get the asp-route-currentFilter below to work for a string array.

```
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Student.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Student.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

What should I change to do that?

Comment: You mean that you want to filter with multiple conditions, right?

Comment: I want to filter with a select box that has the "multiple" attribute. This shows up in the URL as https://localhost:44386/MyPage?SearchString=foo&SearchString=bar but gets to my C# as a string array.

Comment: Try this: var result = from p in studentIQ where searchString.Any(val => p.LastName.Contains(val))
           select p;

Comment: I know how to do that portion, it's the next page and previous page links I'm struggling with.

Comment: @AndyL Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`asp-route-CurrentFilter` could not assign an array.You could use `@Url.Page` to assign custom route data.Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773098/how-do-i-pass-an-array-of-values-via-anchor-tag-helper).

```
public string[] CurrentFilter { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder,string[] currentFilter,string[] searchString,int? pageIndex)
```

.cshtml:

```
<a href="@Url.Page("./Index", 
                    new {
                         sortOrder= Model.CurrentSort,
                         currentFilter = Model.CurrentFilter, 
                         pageIndex= Model.Student.PageIndex +1
                    })"
                    class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
Next</a>
```